# How to set the location of the button to fixed even when on scroll?

Tags: c#, winforms

Been searching for hours and I can't seem to find a solution on this. I'd like to set my button to fixed even when the form is on scroll. Can anyone help?

Comment: Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23013976/3622 from user @TaW

Comment: Your question is very broad. Too broad. Looking for a solution is one thing. Have you tried _creating_ a solution? One obvious possibility is to place everything scrollable inside a `Panel` (which has scrolling enabled) rather than being direct children of the `Form`, and leave the `Button` a direct child of the `Form`. Then, scrolling the other controls, which are children of the `Panel` should not affect the `Button`. But frankly, with such a vague question, there's a wide variety of possible answers, and it's not clear at all which of those might be of interest to you.

Comment: try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4390300/how-to-make-a-floating-control

Comment: I have a form and I have set it on autoscroll. As I have a submit button positioned on the top of the form, I'd like to put a control to it that will set its position to 'fixed' as I think it will make the button move along as the form scrolls up and down. 

I tried doing this:

buttonSubmit.Location = new Point(0 + this.AutoScrollPosition.X, 0 + this.AutoScrollPosition.Y);
this.Controls.Add(buttonSubmit);
buttonSubmit.BringToFront();

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not working, even when one of the sites I've checked said that it's the way how to do it. Although, I'm not really sure as I'm not so good in programming...

Comment: Also, I've already checked the link you have sent, and I'm yet to try it. Thanks, Sir.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using a FlowLayoutPanel in your form for scrolling? More information would help us help you. So would adding some code snippets.

For the time being, have you considered putting the button above (or below, or to the side, or wherever you want it to be fixed) the scrollable component in your app? That way, it remains in the spot you want it while scrolling occurs in the scrollable area?

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I just started working on it and adding the necessary objects into the FlowLayoutPanel, and made it scrollable, then placed the button above the container. I think this will do instead of trying what I wanted to do to the main form directly.